# Restore chat history on WhatsApp - different number

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I made the mistake of doing this in the following order:

1. Backing up my WhatsApp data
2. Changing number
3. Changing phone

Because the data is associated with my previous number (which I don't have a SIM for) - I can't restore it on my new phone. Can anyone help? Do you think the data can be restored to a different number on the same phone (and same account)? I know some people have suggested moving the CRYPT14 database...

Comment: You should have followed the official instructions: https://faq.whatsapp.com/2959230197442405/?locale=en_US